# Depth field by means of 'Stereo' instead of 'IR' functionality

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, google-project-tango

I'm currently researching if a Tango device would be suitable for an application I am working on.  What I need is a vision based depth field and am currently testing with OpenCV based (Disparity Map) stereo vision.  Most of the depth sensing information I've read so far refers to the two 'IR' based technologies, structured light and time of flight.  Specifically refereed to on these pages:

https://developers.google.com/tango/overview/depth-perception
https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/c/c-depth-perception

Due to the limited distance and sensitivity to environmental influences of IR, I would need to use the 'Stereo' functionality.  My question is in the C API where do you select which of these three modes?  Is this in the TangoConfig? Do all 3 still return a TangoPointCloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't have any specific information on the Tango device, the 'stereo' method of getting a dense disparity map (and from there a dense depth map) relies on having two RGB images taken from different positions.

The high level version of this is that if you know the relative position and orientation of the camera(s) when the images were captured, and some internal properties of the camera, you can compute the relative offset of each point in one image from the corresponding point in the other image. (A good description is here https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/hzbook2/HZepipolar.pdf)

From this, you can compute a dense depth map.

OpenCV does provide functions which support doing this (http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html) but I don't know if the Tango device wraps these up nicely or whether you'd be expected to do your own motion tracking and image capture.

Comment: Hi Dave, if 'Tango device wraps this up nicely' is exactly what I'm asking.  I asked [this](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/12089/googles-tango-how-it-works-and-whats-special-about-the-hardware) question earlier trying to understand how the stereo mode would work because I only know of stereo vision with two identical (regarding lenses, exposure time, pixel size, and even element) RGB cameras, and from I understand of the Tango hardware the cameras are actually all different (RGB-I, Wide-angle, etc), so if they have stereo mode the algorithm for disparity map must be very special.

Comment: Hi Nate,  you can still do stereo reconstruction from a single camera, it just requires that the camera moves in between capturing images (and you know *how* it moved - which is not a problem for Tango with it's accelerometer and gyro). In fact, a continuous video stream from a single RGB camera is plenty for 3D reconstruction so it is possible.

Comment: Just took a look at the Tango APIs. Given PoseProvider, TangoImageBuffer and TangoCameraIntrinsics it feels like you could hand roll a dense disparity map algorithm using OpenCV and then use this to update Tango3DReconstruction using PROJECTIVE mode.

Comment: Answered your other question too :)

Answer (score 0):

The TangoPointCloud is a 3D map of based on Depth Map which **requires** you to use the IR on the device.

Each point in the map is a distance of how far the device is from that specific point.  There are examples https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c you can choose the CPP Point Cloud example to get you started in using the Point Cloud system for your functionality.

From my (limited) understanding the stereo data just helps place 3D objects inside the depth map so your objects appear more integrated with your virtual or augmented environment.

Comment: Hello Ali, thanks for feedback.  Yes that's what I gathered from the the examples I was looking at as I couldn't find information on how to actually change between the 3 depth map technologies.  I will say, though, the first link definitely makes it sound as if you can get a depth map without the IR sensor (and technically it should be possible, but maybe not part of the API?) however it seems that's more of a general description of the technologies behind the API.